# Eclipse plugin development: Is plugin update or uninstall/install really clean?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, lifecycle

While developing [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org), I found that [some bugs don't arise immediately but after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091321/eclipse-plugin-activator-cannot-be-resolved-is-it-ok-to-call-activator-from-r), when combination of updates, restarts happens.

**Is plugin update or uninstall/install really clean?**

I develop and use installing for update, then use newer version until I got time/idea to improve. However as said above I ran into situation when Eclipse behaves differently after the new feature have been used for several days.

Is there some information that must be read about plugin install life-cycle, that mentions some not so evident behavior.

UPDATE: Some problem were in Autumn 2013 when we were switching to tycho build. Also around that time Eclipse Kepler 4.3.1 was released.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? Equinox installs/uninstalls/updates bundles transactionally, but that doesn't mean that externally-stored preferences will get managed the same way.

Comment: I mean, is it possible that uninstall leaves some parts of registry changes? Now when externally-stored preferences where mentioned, was it usual procedure to remove them?

Comment: This question was actually not about clean uninstall, but about what can cause problem after plugin updates. Because most people have read "clean" as main word, and I don't have other, I leave as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not "clean". Moreover when you do uninstall, no files are deleted, Eclipse would just prevent plugin from loading on the startup. 
If you really want to remove the plugin you need to

- Uninstall it via UI
- Delete the plugin files in the file system
- Remove plugin settings from workspace or create a new one.

Here is some interesting info for you:

> There is no mechanism within Eclipse to permanently and physically
>   uninstall a feature and its plug-ins. The process to physically and
>   permanently remove an undesirable feature and its plug-ins is a manual
>   process that should be done when Eclipse is not running. In order to
>   do, you will have to manually remove the files there associated with
>   the feature from the eclipse/features directory and its plug-ins from
>   the eclipse/plugins directory. Be very cautious as to which files you
>   delete, and always have a backup of your Eclipse directory. If you
>   remove the wrong files from these directories, you may have quite some
>   trouble restoring your Eclipse to a stable state. Therefore, unless
>   your hard disk storage capacity is extraordinarily limited, it is
>   recommended that you simply leave the physical files in place.
>
> Note that when manually removing plugins as described above, it is
>   likely that some metadata will still cached by Eclipse. This can lead
>   to problems later on. Running Eclipse with the -clean option may help
>   with that, as it causes Eclipse to clean the cached metadata. See the
>   Running Eclipse help page for details about this option.

Source: [http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in?)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this ideally, because the plugins designed for eclipse leave their temp access files even if they are uninstalled, to do so, you will have to follow the steps:

- Uninstall the Plugin: You can use the Eclipse UI directly. Go to Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details, select the software you no longer want and click Uninstall.
- Delete the Present temp Files in the System, make sure to re-check the dependencies(Note: Removing Dependent Plugins might cause Eclipse to stop Working).
- Remove the plugins from the workspace, or in short you can re-configure a new workspace.

This would be removing the plugins, but removing its traces manually.

ref#[Link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F)